# Neo4J Status Monitoring?

Tags: neo4j, monitoring, status, health-monitoring

I have to monitor if Neo4j is ready and is up and running. 
I understand that there are some REST status codes.

Is there a status code and/or method for querying the status of Neo4j?

I think there is a "neo4j status" command. 
However, I do not necessarily want to launch a shell to execute that command.

I would like to programatically query for Neo4j's status via Python.

The Neo4j REST status code notes that the HTTP code does not correspond to Neo4j's status, which makes sense. 
Also, I do not think I should necessarily hit Neo4j's web front end:
e.g. http://neo4jhost:7474/browser/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j Enterprise edition has a lot of JMX beans you can use for monitoring, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/operations-monitoring.html.

AFAIK there are also JMX bridge implementation for python out there.